# Unable to install Mapbox with Unity Errors (CS0234) appearing in Console

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-unity

I just imported the Unity SDK into my project and I'm getting several errors CS0234 in the console. I'm using Unity 2021.1.0f1, attached is an image with the errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hello there are several ways to solve this error:(but im going to give you one at the meanwhile.)
i saw that you are using windows so go to windows and then go to Package manager.
and install some things(that are needed to your projects.)
this error happens just beacause you havnt install thing that are neede to this to this sdk.
(this happend to me while i was using mapbox.)

Comment: the easiest way is just to install XR Plugin Management.